# React Native Firebase - When to fetch data

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm just looking for some recomendations on what would be best practise in my scenario.

So I have an app that has a private chat function using firebase. I have a list of products on the home page and when you click 'buy' it takes you to a private chat between you and the user who is selling the item.

The problem I am facing is that I am checking firebase to see if the chat between yourself and seller exists already. If it does then go to the chat page. Once on chat page fetch all messages.

The problem with this is by the time its checked if the chat exists and then fetches the chat messages its around 3 seconds (good signal). But 3 seconds is a long time to wait for a chat to load.

How do apps like WhatsApp show the chats straight away as soon as you click on it? Does it fetch the data on app loading before doing anything else?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the WhatsApp use the local storage of device, that's why the fetch is has a good signal, you could use local storage for the messages and create number for each message and get last number  of the messages downloaded and fetch only messages after this number

Comment: Thank you. I thought I may have to do that as much as I didn't want to. I think I will use redux-persist as someone else commented (now delete).